# Убрать из загрузки ненужные файлы [ASP.NET MVC 3; WebMatrix 2]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

Доброго времени суток.

Я публикую свой ASP.NET MVC 3 проект на сервер с помощью программы WebMatrix 2. Она удобна в использовании, позволяет загружать только измененные файлы, но в ней есть одна большая проблема - она загружает все файлы проекта. Это исходный код, файл проекта, файлы от debug-компиляции и другое. Можно ли как-то автоматически отсечь эти файлы из загрузки?

В настройках публикации Visual Studio 2010 есть удобная опция - Только необходимые для запуска приложения файлы. Вот хотелось бы что-нибудь аналогичное.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, написал себе небольшую программку, которая копирует только нужные файлы. Исходник:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace CopyMvcFiles
{
    class Program
    {
        static string _sourceMvcDirName;
        static string _destMvcDirName;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] options = File.ReadAllLines("Options.txt");

            _sourceMvcDirName = options[0];
            _destMvcDirName = options[1];

            CopyMvcDir("App_Data", ".mdf", ".dat");
            CopyMvcDir("bin", ".dll");
            CopyMvcDir("Content");
            CopyMvcDir("Scripts");
            CopyMvcDir("Views");

            CopyMvcFile("Global.asax");
            CopyMvcFile("Web.config");
        }

        static void CopyMvcFile(string fileName)
        {
            string sourceFileName = Path.Combine(_sourceMvcDirName, fileName);
            string destFileName = Path.Combine(_destMvcDirName, fileName);

            File.Copy(sourceFileName, destFileName, true);
        }

        static void CopyMvcDir(string path, params string[] searchPatterns)
        {
            string sourceDirName = Path.Combine(_sourceMvcDirName, path);
            string destDirName = Path.Combine(_destMvcDirName, path);

            CopyDir(sourceDirName, destDirName, searchPatterns);
        }

        static void CopyDir(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, params string[] searchPatterns)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(sourceDirName))
            {
                return;
            }

            if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
            }

            IEnumerable<string> files;

            if (searchPatterns.Length == 0)
            {
                files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirName);
            }
            else
            {
                files = GetFiles(sourceDirName, searchPatterns);
            }

            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
                string destination = Path.Combine(destDirName, fileName);

                File.Copy(file, destination, true);
            }

            var directories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(sourceDirName);

            foreach (string directory in directories)
            {
                string dirName = Path.GetFileName(directory);
                string destination = Path.Combine(destDirName, dirName);

                CopyDir(directory, destination, searchPatterns);
            }
        }

        static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string sourceDirName, params string[] searchPatterns)
        {
            return from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirName)
                   let extension = Path.GetExtension(file)
                   where searchPatterns.Contains(extension)
                   select file;
        }
    }
}
```